# How do I use a Stripes action as my web app's welcome file?

Tags: java, stripes

I have an action bean named HomeActionBean, which Stripes has bound to the URL "Home.action". The URL binding works. Now I would like to use "Home.action" as my welcome file, like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Home.action</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This does not work with the default configuration from the Stripes quickstart guide. I get the error

> A request made it through to some part of Stripes without being wrapped in a StripesRequestWrapper. [...]

I figured out that I can make it work if I add the line

```
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

to my web.xml like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

My question is: Is this the appropriate way of using a Stripes action as a welcome file? Does adding that line with "FORWARD" in it to my web.xml have other, possibly unwanted consequences?

Answer (score 1):

To bind an action bean to the homepage URL you should use: `@UrlBinding("/")` like this:

```
@UrlBinding("/")
public class HomepageAction {
   // .. action bean code..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just one more thing: in order to make this work, I had to make the StripesDispatcher the default servlet for the app, by giving it the url-pattern "/". Being a Stripes beginner, I'm not quite sure of the repercussions of that. But my guess is it's a good thing. Now I should probably override the methods handleActionBeanNotFound and/or findView of nameBasedActionResolver in order to gracefully handle requests that go nowhere, right?

Comment: With that URL pattern you indicate that the Stripes controller will handle all requests. The Stripes controller will delegate these request to the correct action beans and if none can be matched it will respond with a 404. This is normal behavior for any web server and I am not sure in what kind of scenario one correctly would want to respond to any URL receive. But you can let the 404 be handled by an action bean, see: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user/10617